# How do i send clicks manually to google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a ToC with all the links in the format as "#id-link". I can generate the href as anything i want easily. However i dont think adding `?utm_source=...` will send google analytics the click events (does it!? i was looking at [How do I tag my links?](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55518) at the time)

How do i send clicks to google analytics?

Comment: Have you tried using a proxy like TOR and a different browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any point you can send page views to Google using the TrackPageView command:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/document/sectionName.html']);
```

So in your ToC, for example:

```
<a href="#links" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/document.html/links']);">Links</a>
```